# User receives "lifetime" error when renewing membership

Tags: civimember, renewals

He have multiple memberships available. Some are a 1 year duration and some are lifetime memberships. Recently, some users who have a lifetime membership A try to renew annual membership B and get the following message: "You already have a lifetime membership and cannot select a membership with a shorter term." This has happened twice in the last few weeks. We have had the same memberships set up for quite a while so we're not sure why we are seeing this now. Does anyone have a recommendation for preventing this?

Comment: Also posted in Civi Chat: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/snuah7s9upgj98kccnp8wynkny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system won't allow users to change their membership type if they already have a lifetime membership. Also, the system can only have one membership for a contact of each organization. In case you want to have a lifetime membership and regular membership for a contact, you will need to create a membership type for a different organization i.e life time membership type belonging to Org A and Regular membership type to Org B.